# Using a simple while loop to solve the linked list cycle in Python returns an AssertionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, while-loop, linked-list

I'm working through a udemy course on Data Structures, and when I got to the section on linked lists, I was given the classic "check if the linked list cycles" problem. I came up with a solution that passed all tests. The solution explanation video took a totally different route, so I thought I'd test my solution on the leetcode challenge to see if I was perhaps missing something. I implemented the following code

```
class Solution(object):
    def hasCycle(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        initial_node = head   # set initial node value

        if not head.next:  # if next node is set to None, return False, not a cycle
            return False

        while head.next:  # while head.next is not set to None, check if the next node is the initial node
            if head.next == initial_node:
                return True
            head = head.next  # set the new node to the next node and repeat the check until you hit the end, or the original node

        return False  # if the last checked node is None, break out of the while loop and return False
```

which passed both tests in the Udemy challenge, but I get an assertion error when I run it in the leetcode challenge. The description of the challenge is as follows:

"Given a linked list, determine if it has a cycle in it."

When I run this as is, I get the error `Line 15: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'`

`[]
no cycle`

I tried taking next out of line 15 to make it just `if not head:` which let it get past line 15, but then I got the following error:

`Time Limit Exceeded`

`[3,2,0,-4]
tail connects to node index 1`

Where am I making the mental misstep?

Comment: Do you assume that a cycle has to return to the head? What happens if the cycle is to the middle of the list?

Comment: Ah, I never thought about that, that wasn't one of the test cases I was originally provided so it didn't even register. I can probably work with that, thanks!

Comment: I'm still confused as to why it returns an AssertionError with my edge case check being set to head.next though

Comment: `AttributeError` - you don't test for an empty list, i.e. `head == None`. `None` has no `next` attribute.

Comment: You should indicate which line of your code is line 15.

Comment: I was under the impression that linked lists aren't actual list objects and an "empty" list would just mean you never created any nodes, is that not the case? Additionally, `if not head.next` is line 15

Comment: Yes, which is why it is `None` not `[]`. A linked list of one element is `Item1 -> None` and a linked list of zero elements is just `None`.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification, I think I have enough information to work with now.